# Cannot insert the value NULL into column - But No Null values exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `CTE` to update `lTesterID` column in table `Employee` to a valid ID randomly chosen from the table provider.

But I get this error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'lTesterID ', table 'Employee'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Even though there are no `Null` values as I'm excluding it in `cteTable4`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
WITH    cteTable3
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS n ,
                        lTesterID
                        FROM     Employee
               WHERE lTesterID= 0 
             ),
        cteTable4
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS n ,
                        ISNULL(lTesterID,0) AS lTesterID
               FROM     Provider
               WHERE    Active = 'True'
                        AND lTesterID IS NOT NULL
             )
    UPDATE  cteTable3
    SET     lTesterID = ( SELECT  lTesterID
                            FROM    cteTable4
                            WHERE   cteTable3.n = cteTable4.n
                AND lTesterID IS NOT NULL
                          )
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You are joining the CTE's on `cteTable3.n = cteTable4.n` in a correlated subquery. `cteTable3.lTesterID` will be updated with `NULL` where the subquery returns zero rows. That will happen if you have less rows returned from `cteTable4` than you have from `cteTable3`.